# google colab : Other people can't see files

Tags: google-colaboratory

I'm using google colab.

I shared link with other people, but problem happens; my working directory list doesn't appear to other people

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Bxkd.png)

This is my directory with my ID.
But when other people see there is only 'sample_data'

How can I show my working directory to others and work same time?

Answer (score 0):

Share the same directory with them, including the Colab note as well.